# How to select a seat programatically in SeatMap anychart?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, anychart

To support features like

1. Searching for a specific seat in a large floorplan
2. Pick seats in sets, as in selecting the adjacent seat also when one seat is clicked

how can I programmatically select a seat in SeatMap with SVG?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible via the `select()` function of the series. It works like this:

```
// create chart
var chart = anychart.seatMap({YOUR_DATA});

// get series intance
var series = chart.getSeries(0);

// select seat with indexes 0 and 3
series.select([0, 3]);
```